# How to np.save from input path to output path?

Tags: python, numpy, kaggle

The following code saves features to the same directory as the image dataset, but the input directory is not writable on Kaggle, so how do I save them to the kaggle/working directory instead? Possible?

```
for img, path in tqdm(image_dataset):
  batch_features = image_features_extract_model(img)
  batch_features = tf.reshape(batch_features,
                              (batch_features.shape[0], -1, batch_features.shape[3]))

  for bf, p in zip(batch_features, path):
    path_of_feature = p.numpy().decode("utf-8")
    np.save(path_of_feature, bf.numpy())
```

Comment: I don't understand why you use `p.numpy().decode("utf-8")` to create path. And `Current Working Dirrectory` you can get with `os.getcwd()`. And you can create path with `os.path.join(folder, subfolder, subsubfolder, ..., filename)`. There are other useful functions in `os.path` - ie. to get only directory without filename or to get filename (basename) without directory, to get full path, etc. You could check documentation.

Comment: The p is the path to the image in the dataset. Numpy is used to create the feature file which has the same name as the image, but with an .npy extension, e.g. ../path/to/image.jpg.npy